# Most simple, easy to service and update DIY spam/virus filtering SMTP gateway

Tags: email, email-server, spam, spamassassin, clamav

I run email for several companies, and I want to set up my own SMTP gateway to migrate their domains off hosted spam filtering services.

I wanted an opinion from someone who *actually* runs email operations, what's to your mind the best setup I could get? I am trying to get a reasonable balance between price and time expenditure running one.

I have been considering to setup my own postfix/spamassassin/clamav server, but concerned with complexity. Is there an easy, automated way to setup one? It would also be nice to have some way to monitor queues, disk and other server health related items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at MailCleaner [commercial](http://www.mailcleaner.net/) or [Open Source](http://www.mailcleaner.org/).

Comment: looks very nice and exactly what I'm looking for. I'll test it on the weekend

Comment: very nice product (open source branch that is), but it apparently went stale after last update on january 2009. no new updates...

Comment: Not really stale. The main dev has been travelling much of this year but there will be a major update very shortly. There's a poll running on the support forum to see if it should be released now or to wait for the latest Windows virtualisation drivers to be included in the kernel, which is believed to be just a couple of weeks away.

Comment: The project is really alive but sourceforge does not see all the updates of the product.
MailCleaner Anti Spam is a business anti spam gateway installed between your mail infrastructure and the Internet. It offers professional protection against viruses and spam.
more info for the [Community Edition](http://www.mailcleaner.org) or the [Business Anti Spam](http://www.mailcleaner.net). With the community edition you have exactly the same product but no automatic update of the filtering rules (less filtering quality) and no support ...